# How does the OS determine which interface to go for a duplicated link-local address range?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have a Linux server with a lot of containers. Each container (with an isolated network namespace) generates a `veth` interface on the host, and the IPv6 routing table has a lot of entries for `fe80::/64`, including 4 physical links. When I ping an address in that CIDR block, how does the system find out which interface the ARP should query from?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you must specify the interface explicitly, otherwise the OS simply returns an error.

On Windows, if you specify an [ambiguous address](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/link-local-and-site-local-addresses-2#ambiguous-scoped-addresses), the OS tries to send out a Neighbour Solicitation (i.e. "ARP query") to each interface in turn until it receives a reply.

On FreeBSD, the OS will first send out a Neighbour Solicitation for that address **on all interfaces** at once, then it'll use whichever interface was the first to receive a NA response to the NS.

**Specifying the interface**

In IPv6 you can specify an interface for link-scope addresses by suffixing it with `%idx` for the "zone index", or by specifying `.sin6_scope_id` in the socket API. This works for link-local unicast fe80:: addresses as well as link-scope multicast ff02:: addresses.

The API stores the interface as an integer, so in all operating systems it can be the "ifindex" as seen in `ip link` (Linux) or `netsh interface ipv6 show interface` (Windows).

Additionally, Linux and BSDs accept the interface *name* in textual addresses (e.g. `fe80::1%eth0`) and the API automatically resolves it to the correct index.

Comment: Interestingly Debian automatically adds "some" interface when I ping link-local address of a host, while Rocky returns an error. What makes Debian "guess" which I can turn on in Rocky?

Comment: @ВладимирТюхтин: Most likely a difference between `ping` using 'raw IP' sockets (the traditional way Unix `ping` works, using a setuid binary to craft the whole IP packet) and 'ICMP datagram' sockets (a later addition, unprivileged mechanism specifically for sending ICMP Echo packets). The former method seems to result in the socket being bound to the first non-loopback interface if not otherwise specified (it doesn't do any guessing). Try `ping -e 0 fe80::abcd` to force it to use the 'raw socket' method and compare the results.

Comment: So I tried. With or without `-e 0` Debian sends pings through interface associated with default gateway (though it is not the right one). Rocky though returns an error. Rocky's ping does not even support `-e` flag. My guess is its ping implementation, nothing to do with linux. To add, I also tried systemd-resolved with LLMNR enabled. If (on Debian) I ping a short name of a host, ping always finds the right interface. Now what is so special in systemd-resolved? For sure it knows the interface LLMNR came from, but interface is not part of name resolution, is it?

Comment: It actually is. In IPv6 the struct sockaddr_in6 has a separate field for the interface index (i.e. it can represent the whole "fe80::123%eth0" address), and the name resolution modules don't just imitate DNS – they work directly within the getaddrinfo() function, which will return a full struct sockaddr that you can pass directly to connect() or sendto(). (The function takes a hostname and a service name → you get the address with port number already filled in, and in this case it also has the zone index field filled in as well.)